# Union of a Topological space (or differentiable manifold) and its Universal cover (or any other cover, say a normal cover), with identification

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

[image]

In the picture I want to illustrate how the universal cover of the circle, the real line, and the circle when identified at a point yields and interesting space (interesting topology and geometry). Since a covering space of another space has the nice structure of disjoint homeomorphic neighborhoods, I am interested in making identification of a set in the space with one of the preimagies of the set in its cover. As in the picture, a point in the circle is identified with a point in the real line. What is the topic of study of these special cases of "surgery" (here I am not using the boundaries but sets in the spaces themselves, because of the nice structure)? Are there any interesting theorems concerning this idea?

My interest comes from trying to understand if the interior of black holes could be understood as a cover of the Riemannian manifold outside the horizon with identifications at the horizon or vice versa, and trying to understand if Deck transformations can be associated with degrees of freedom of geometric structures that may be constructed in the space, and understanding Black hole entropy. Is such an idea applied to the study of manifolds in physics?